# Groovy: rewriting two functions which differ by one line only into one?

Tags: groovy, closures

Given we have a loop which looks like this:

```
for (some a in someArray) {    
 doSomething

 someClassA.set(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)

 doSOmething
}
```

and

```
for (some a in someArray) {    
 doSomething

 someClassB.set(fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ)

 doSOmething
}
```

Is it possible NOT to dublicate the description of the 2 loop block in Groovy?

In other words, may I write some single function which will do BOTH the jobs?

Comment: As this code stands it is kinda hard to generalize it. We need to know were those `field*` variables come from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure which encapsulates that single line logic and pass it to a method, which loops and executes the block:

```
def doA = { some -> some.set(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) }
def doB = { some -> some.set(fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ) }


def doLoop(closure) {
    for ( a in someArray) {    
        doSomething

        closure(a)

        doSOmething
    }
}

doLoop doA

doLoop doB
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like I cannot compile it if fieldX are not primitives, but values of some variables from doLoop. For example fieldB is actually someArray[3] and it will not compile. Am I right?

Comment: @MiamiBeach it'd be easier to help if you'd come up with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy supports duck-typing. Which means if your two classes set-method have the same signature, you just call it on both classes:

```
class A {
  String x
}

class B {
  String x
}


list = [new A(), new B()]

def loop(def list) {
  for (e in list) {
    e.setX("myX of ${e.class}")
    println e.x
  }
}

loop(list)
```